# Windows Service is not appearing in services list after installation using InstallShield LE From VS 2013

Tags: c#, windows-services, installshield

I've created a windows service in c#, using Visual Studio 2013 I pretty much followed this: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/cb88b2/simple-steps-to-create-setup-file-using-install-shield-le-fr/

I created a setup project, as instructed in the article, and ran it. It installs my service to c:\program files(*86)\Company Name\My product Name etc., however, it does not then appear in the services list.

can you please help me What am i missing?

PS: I already tried to install this service manually using visual studio command prompt, and  its working fine. But I am not able to install it using setup project which I created using Installshiled light edition which VS2013 provided inbuilt.

Comment: Did you add that service under Services tab in InstallShield ?

Comment: i am not getting u @AjitMedhekar

Comment: this may help you.
http://blogs.flexerasoftware.com/installtalk/2014/10/using-installshield-to-create-an-installation-that-installs-windows-services.html

Comment: You've linked to a tutorial on creating a setup - telling us precisely nothing about how you created your service. Have you, at the least, got to the point where you install the service manually and it executes as a service?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever i edited my question, yes i didn’t gave more details , because frankly saying I don’t have any experience to install Winservice using installshield.

Comment: Show us your Install.cs class please.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that you've already added an installer class to your service project.(If not, serivce.cs deisgn view, properties pane - bottom left "add installer" link)

In your solution explorer - Setup project, double click the "Files" item listed under step 2.

In the bottom right quad, right click your service's primary output (if it is not located there, add it) and select properties

In the window that pops up, select the second tab "COM & .NET Settings"

At the bottom of this pane, there should be a check box "Installer Class" - Ensure this is **checked**